# Problem accessing the value of the json with a point in its name

Tags: php, json

I need to access the value of the json that contains a point in its name.

I would like to access the "proy_sim.name" field but I do not know how

```
{        
    "prsp_sol": [
        {
            "proy_sim.name": "Vehículos",
            "prsp_def.name": "TRACTOR"  
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After decoding with `json_decode()` you'll realize that there is an additional array you're not accounting for:

```php
$json = '{
    "prsp_sol": [
        {
            "proy_sim.name": "Vehículos",
            "prsp_def.name": "TRACTOR"
        }
    ]
}';

$decoded = json_decode($json, true); // true makes it an array
print_r($decoded);

echo $decoded['prsp_sol'][0]['proy_sim.name'];
//-----------------------^ additional nested array
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [prsp_sol] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [proy_sim.name] => Vehículos
                    [prsp_def.name] => TRACTOR
                )
        )
)

Vehículos
```

Here is an [example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/03b803e7502618e4debfe5e5d2e941e9cf0de61b)

The point in the name is irrelevant.